# How to compile Javascript files from a folder structure into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a folder full of JavaScript files:

[image: Folder structure]

And within each file is a function definition, e.g.:

```
function() {
    return true;
}
```

I want to be able to build these files into a single JavaScript object which uses the name and contents of each file under the "foo" folder as property names and values.

So the result of the above would be:

```
var foo = {
    aFunction: function() {
        return true;
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        return true;
    },
    yetAnotherFunction: function() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This seems like something that Grunt would be great for, but I can't find any existing plugin that does this, and I'm not sure how to write one that does this myself. How do?

Comment: You can use the [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) task.

Comment: Thanks! I dug a bit further into concat and figured out how to do this by writing a simple custom process function.